# How do I move messages between queues in Websphere MQ 6

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

Is there a (Linux) command to move all messages from one queue in Websphere MQ 6 to another queue?

I have a queue that has a defined backout queue, but I want to know how to transfer all the messages back to the original queue once the error preventing the messages from being processed has been corrected.

Is there a GUI tool that can do this? IBM Websphere MQ Explorer 6 does not seem to have an option for this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a GUI try [SupportPac MO71](http://bit.ly/SupportPacMO71).
For a command-line tool, try [SupportPac MA01](http://bit.ly/SupportPacMA01).

Both of these can move messages between queues, from queue to file, file to queue and so forth.  The main SupportPac landing page [is here](http://bit.ly/SupportPacs).